# Arrange 15 animals in 15 cages

Tags: combinatorics

Five tigers, five lions and five cheetahs are going to be hosted in $15$ consecutive cages in the zoo. Due to some restrictions in the zoo regulations, we cannot put the tigers in the $5$ leftmost cages, the lions in the $5$ middle cages and the cheetahs in the $5$ rightmost cages. Can you calculate all possible arrangements?

If all animals were the same, there would be $15!$ different ways. Now that we have $5$ of every kind, if there were no restrictions from the zoo regulations, we would have $\frac{15!}{5!5!5!}$. I don't know though how to apply the restrictions :(

Comment: The description of the restriction is somewhat ambiguous.  Do you mean, for example, that you can't put *any* of the tigers in any of the leftmost cages, or that you can put *some* of them there as long as you don't put *all* of them there (and the same for the lions in the middle and the cheetahs in the rightmost cages)?

Comment: What do you mean "if all animals were the same"? Undistinguishable? In that case you'd have essentially $1$ arrangement. $15!$ is the solution for $15$ _different_ (i.e. distinguishable) animals without restrictions.

Comment: @lesath82, I think the OP meant to say "different" instead of "the same."  That's the only way I can make sense of the $15!$.

Comment: Indeed, Lions are a bad example. Zoo visitors can tell Lions from Tigers, but their caretakers can tell the Lions apart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you cannot place *any* of the tigers in *any* of the leftmost cages and so on. For the moment the $5$ members of each animal family are undistinguishable. I'll follow Pieter's notation with animals $a, b$ and $c$ and cages $A, B$ and $C$ with forbidden $a$ in $A$, $b$ in $B$ and $c$ in $C$.

Start placing the five $a$'s. You have $10$ places available so you have ${10 \choose 5} = 252$ arrangements. These can be cathegorized in three cases:

$I)$ all $5$ $a$ animals in the same cage ($B$ or $C$);

$II)$ $4$ animals in one cage and $1$ in the other;

$III)$ $3$ in one and $2$ in the other.

Each of these cases counts $\times 2$, since the roles of $B$ and $C$ can be swapped. Let's see how many arrangements correspond to each case:

$I)$ there is only one way to place $5$ undistinguishable $a$ animals in, say, $B$. Considering the $\times 2$ factor (you could place them in $C$) we have the first $2$ of said $252$;

$II)$ $4$ $a$ animals can be placed in $5$ ways in $B$ (easy if you think about the $5$ possibilities for the "hole") and the remaining one can be placed in $5$ places in $C$, so there are $25$ arrangements. Invert $B$ and $C$ and we have other $50$ of the $252$;

$III)$ $3$ $a$ animals can be placed in $5 \choose 3$ ways in $B$ and the remaining $2$ in $5 \choose 2$ ways in $C$. This gives ${5 \choose 3}\cdot {5 \choose 2}=\frac{5!}{3!2!}\cdot \frac{5!}{2!3!}=10\cdot 10=100$ possibilities. And we have the final $200$ arrangements of the $252$.

Now we have to place another species. Let's consider first the one that has been more constrained. Looking at each case we have:

$I)$ consider again that all $a$ animals were placed in $B$, then all $c$ animals must be placed in $A$. Finally all animals $b$ must go in $C$. Only one possible arrangement for each of the $2$, so this case $(I)$ brings exactly $2$ arrangements;

$II)$ in $B$ there is one "hole", and since it cannot be filled with a $b$ we must place there a $c$. Now we have $5$ ways to place the remaining $4$ $c$'s in $A$. Finally we are forced to place the $b$'s in the only possible way. So, $5$ alternatives for each of the $50$ make case $(II)$ give $250$ valid arrangements;

$III)$ again $2$ holes in $B$ must be filled with $c$ animals. The remaining $3$ can be placed in $A$ in ${5 \choose 3}=10$ ways. Again $b$'s take the places that are left. So $10\cdot 200$ contribute with $2000$ arrangements within case $(III)$.

The final total amount of arrangements that comply with the given restriction is:

$$2 + 250 + 2000 = \fbox{2252}$$

If you want the animals to be distinguishable, you have to consider the permutations within each species, so multiply the result by $5!\cdot5!\cdot 5!$, and we're done!

Comment: This is indeed my $\sum_{n=0}^{5} 
{5\choose n}^3$ solution.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that. But it took me some effort to understand your indeed extremely simple and elegant result. Probably the first half of your answer is somewhat misleading, and perhaps you could explain the rest a little more, but anyway you have my upvote

Comment: Forgot to tag you @Pieter21

Comment: I indeed needed to clean up my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let's turn it into letters, animals $a,b,c$ and cages $A,B,C$, where $a$ can't be in $A$.

We have to decide on the number $n$ of animals $b$ to place in $A$. This can be anything from $0$ to $5$. So we later will have to sum over all these options.

As soon as you place $n$ animals $b$ in cage $A$, $(5-n)$ animals $b$ need to be placed in $C$. The rest of $C$ will be filled with $n$ times $a$, so the number $n$ applies to all three sets of cages!

Within each set of cages, we have $5\choose {n}$ possible placements, so the toal will be:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{5} 
{5\choose n}^3
$$

---

Sidenote to address one of your comments:

If you just look at the first $N$ cages with indistinguishable animals, $$\sum_{n=0}^{N} 
{N\choose n} = 2^N$$ what you observed in one of your comments.

Comment: Maybe we should test with smaller numbers... for example 3 animals of each kind and 9 cages.

Comment: then why not 2?

Comment: Now that I tried it with 3 x 3, I noticed that we only need to check the first 3 cages, which give us 8 different arrangements. Then, regardless what the other 3+3 cages might be, all possible arrangements of the 9 animals, will start with these 8 different arrangements. Therefore the total number is 8. (2^3). I assume that the same applies when we have 5 of each species - therefore 2^5?

Comment: @Alex.vollenga , nope. Name your animals $a_1 .. a_3, b_1..b_3, c_1 .. c_3$, and see that your first three cages can be filled in 6*5*4 ways.

Comment: But a1...a3 cannot be in the first 3 cages, b1...b3 in the 3 middle and c1...c3 in the last 3.

Comment: So the first 3 cages can be any of $b_1,..,c_3$: 6 items in the first one, 5 in the second, 4 in the third.

Comment: But a1, a2, a3 are all the same, and so are b1...b3 and c1...c3. Let's think of it like this: Every cage has a label outside it, either "tiger" or "lion" or "cheetah". So the first 5 cages can be filled in 32 different ways (only with combinations of 2 letters).

Comment: I modified my answer to reflect indistinguishable animals.

Comment: To be honest, @Pieter, I find it somewhat hard to follow your steps. Do they bring to a final result that I can compare with mine?

Comment: So finally, how many? I still believe the total number is 32.

Comment: 32 for what? For the complete problem in my answer I get a much bigger number. I'm pretty confident with it. 252 arrangements only to place the tigers avoiding the leftmost cages... @Alex

Comment: I am so confused... All solutions seem correct, although they are different!